# Swift 2.3 ：open sqlite with Thread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code EXC_I386_INVOP subcode 0x0

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite

I hate this error

> Thread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code EXC_I386_INVOP subcode 0x0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s6pb.jpg

I always have no idea what this appear.

I had google this error, but there are many kinds of condition.

Have any idea?

```
var statement = COpaquePointer()
//var data:NSMutableArray = []
var data: [[String: AnyObject]] = []

func loadData() {

    let db_path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Recipes", ofType: "sqlite")
    var db = COpaquePointer()

    let status = sqlite3_open(db_path!,&db)
    if (status == SQLITE_OK) {
        print("Open the sqlite success!\n")
    }else {
        print("Open the sqlite failed!\n")
    }

    let query_stmt = "SELECT * FROM recipe"
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db , query_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        //self.data.removeAllObjects()
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            var recipeArray: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

            let recipeName = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
            let recipe_name = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(recipeName)) ?? ""

            let recipeType = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)
            let recipe_type = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(recipeType)) ?? ""

            let recipeImage = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)
            let recipe_image = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(recipeImage)) ?? ""

            let recipeIsFavor = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3)
            let recipe_isFavor = Int(recipeIsFavor)

            let recipeUserPhoto = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)
            let recipe_userPhoto = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(recipeUserPhoto)) ?? ""

            let recipeUserName = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)
            let recipe_userName = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(recipeUserName)) ?? ""

            recipeArray["recipeName"] = recipe_name
            recipeArray["recipeType"] = recipe_type
            recipeArray["recipeImage"] = recipe_image
            recipeArray["recipIsFavor"] = recipe_isFavor
            recipeArray["recipeUserPhoto"] = recipe_userPhoto
            recipeArray["recipeUserName"] = recipe_userName

            data.append(recipeArray)
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement)
    }else {
        print("read the sqlite data failed")
    }

}
```

Comment: The first thing to do would be to check if `db_path` is `nil`. – Btw, that `guard let recipe_isFavor = UnsafePointer ...` line does not make much sense to me. Does it compile at all?

Comment: @MartinR yeah, there is something wrong, but I had solved it with this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199900/swift2-3-nsmutabledictionary-store-integer-from-sqlite/40199959?noredirect=1#comment67665396_40199959

Comment: Did you check if `db_path` is nil? – Another problem is that files in the application bundle are *read-only*, so you cannot open the data base read-write, only read-only.

Comment: sorry,how to check if db_path is nil?I just touch sqlite a while. If I want to write & read the data base, what should I do?